# Where is wrong on my $i^i=1$ proof?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

I wanted to calculate $i^i$ ($i$ is an imaginary unit), and I calculated in this way:

$i^i = (i^4)^{i/4} = 1^{i/4} = 1$ (because $1^x = 1$ for any number $x$)

So, I thought that $i^i$ 's one solution is $1$.

Though, in Wolfram Alpha, it says the solution was $e^{2n\pi - \pi/2}$. It doesn't include $1$. What's wrong with my proof?

Comment: Exponents don't work the same when you have negative (or imaginary) bases.

Comment: @Nilknarf So I wrote "one solution" (because there may many solutions)

Comment: Before you can apply the "laws of exponents", you have to define the expressions where you intend to apply them and show the laws hold.  The expression $i^i$ has no well-defined value.

Comment: In the same spirit $$ 1 = 1^{1/2} = \left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^{1/2} = e^{\pi i} = -1$$ !!!

Answer (score 4):

There are some errors. In first place in general $a\neq (a^n)^{1/n}$, otherwise we will had that $-1=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1$.

By the other hand the equation $a=x^n$ have $n$ distinct solutions for $x$ (some times one or two of them are real). Then, in general, we define $x^z:=e^{z\ln x}$, where $\ln$ is understood as the principal value of the complex logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

One of the central questions of complex variable is *what is the logarithm?*  You skirt this blithely.  Pay attention! Open the book by Ahlfors on Complex Variable.

Answer (score 2):

For $z,w\in\mathbb C$, we define exponentiation by $z^w\equiv \exp(w\ln z)$, where here $\ln$ is the complex logarithm. Now it might seem like this doesn't rule out your solution. After all, the exponentiation rules for logarithms says that $n\ln z = \ln(z^n)$. But the complex logarithm is a multi-valued function, and thus any expression involving it is only well-defined once we choose a branch. If we stick to the principal branch (i.e., the one where $|\mathrm{Im}(\ln z)|\le \pi$), then we have to modify the rule to
$$
n\ln z = \ln z^n \;\;\;\mathrm{if} \;|\mathrm{Arg}(z)|\le \pi/n
$$
as otherwise the left hand side would be on a different branch of the complex logarithm.

This then resolves your problem. $|\mathrm{Arg}(i)| = \pi/2 > \pi/4$, so you can't apply the rule.